# Нужна ли запятая в сочетаниях "должен" + пара глаголов в неопределенной форме

Tags: пунктуация

Пример: ***Он должен успеть мне все объяснить.*** Нужна ли запятая между *успеть* и *объяснить*? На мой взгляд, запятая лишняя. Но ворд настойчиво исправляет. Причем такое же замечание пришло от ридера. Как правильно? Помогите, пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Не знаю, какой у Вас ворд, — мой 2007-й ничего не подчёркивает. Конечно, запятая не нужна!

Comment: Во-первых, в каком месте та запятая, о которой Вы говорите? Во-вторых, Ворд как источник пунктуационной нормы никем и никогда не рассматривался.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - да какой бы ни был. Все равно не авторитетно.МАло ли что та ему в программную голову придет.

Comment: я с вами согласна. ВОрд хорош, чтобы поправить перепутанные буквы и опечатки. Запятая подразумевалась после слова УСПЕТЬ. Но тогда получалась бы белиберда.

Comment: _**Olia: Нужна ли запятая между успеть и объяснить?**_ === Не нужна. А вот чуть дальше по тексту запятые нужны:  _Понятия не имею(,) куда идти и что вырубать... Ра перебил ее(,) не дав закончить._ Ворд их не отметил?

Comment: @slava1947 *А вот чуть дальше по тексту...* - загадками изъясняться изволите. Где это "дальше"?

Comment: Ну почему загадками? Olia , думаю, поняла. А "дальше" -- это здесь: https://www.proza.ru/2016/06/05/1431 (автор -- Оля Дэвос).

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо, Слава. Правда,у меня там старый текст. Уже все поправлено. Но менять еще пока рановато. Вообще-то ворд мне нравится. Удобно печатать. И опечатки он хорошо находит. А вот запятые... это какой-то кошмар. Ставишь их ставишь, а все одно, что-то пропустишь ))

Answer (score 1):

Он **должен успеть** мне все **объяснить**.

Не нужна запятая.

**Должен успеть объяснить**  — осложненное составное глагольное сказуемое,  глагольная связка состоит из двух вспомогательных глаголов: **должен** — модальный глагол, **успеть** —  "модально-фазовый" глагол, объяснить — основной глагол.

УСПЕТЬ; св. 1. с инф. Суметь сделать что-л. в срок, своевременно.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо большое всем за ответы! Я очень рада, что у меня еще кое-что осталось от чувства языка, хотя с годами замечаю - запинок становится все больше и больше. Но именно в этом случае дело не только в Ворде. Эту ошибку мне обозначил ридер, хотя я уже его подозревала в переписке вордовских исправлений... ну да ладно. Главное, теперь у меня на одно сомнение меньше. )) Еще раз спасибо всем и отдельное спасибо этому сайту, где так оперативно можно найти ответ!

Comment: То есть, "ридер" - это человек (я имел дело только с планшетными бук-ридерами)? :)

Comment: @Alex_ander Человек! меня тоже немного коробит такое название. Но это не я придумала...

Answer (score 0):

Вы наверняка имели дело с машинным переводом. Машинная орфография (она и на завершающей стадии перевода применяется) тоже не бывает совершенной. Ваш пример иллюстрирует несводимость языка к ограниченному набору правил. Здесь замена некоторых слов теми же частями речи, но с другим смыслом, может привести к случаю, когда запятая нужна. Например:

> Он должен одуматься, ему что-нибудь предложить.

Введение какого-нибудь программного модуля классификации и смысловой сочетаемости глаголов, возможно, исправило бы эту пунктуационную ошибку, но вряд ли можно предусмотреть **всё**, даже если умудриться машинно обработать все существующие орфографические справочники и привлечь к отладке такой программы выдающихся филологов.

Comment: *Вы наверняка имели дело с машинным переводом* - Господь с Вами.  Да при чем тут машинный перевод, если вся ситуация вызвана тем, что в русском глаголы нанизываются друг на друга как бисер на нитку? Успели собраться решить послать купить выпить. Конечно, замена на другие глаголы лишит фразу смысла, но при чем тут машинный перевод???

Comment: Машинный перевод - для иллюстрации несовершенства подобных средств; можно было и на шахматные компьютеры сослаться, но они успешнее конкурируют с человеческим разумом.

Comment: нет. это не перевод. ))

Comment: Никто и не говорил, что это перевод. Просто приведена аналогия с известной многим ситуацией, когда машинный вариант (здесь правка) кажется странным. Не стоит слишком серьёзно относиться к "мнению" машины.

Comment: Ожидания при общении с техникой иногда бывают завышены. В последнее время непросто понять с кем вы общаетесь:  с мощным искусственным интеллектом типа Гугла или Вольфрама, или это просто тупой вордовский спеллчекер  (пардон май датч), скорбное детище несчастного Микрософта.